# MySQL Duplicate index on primary key column?

Tags: mysql, database, innodb, indexing

I'm still confuse on some MySQL documentation regarding INNODB engine index.

Is the primary key on Innodb engine table is automatically index or not?

Do I need to force a duplicate index on the primary key column?

Your help will be much appricated.

thanks

Finau

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primary key is a key by definition. `INDEX` term is synonymous to `KEY`

So just mark field as `PK` and don't create additional indexes.